# PDF.js not working with local file Meteor/Cordova

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, pdf, meteor

I'm finishing an iOS app that I built with Meteor and I've run into an issue that's stopping me from releasing it.

The app needs to display PDF's so I decided to use [PDF.js](https://atmospherejs.com/pascoual/pdfjs)

I'm using this code:

```
Template.pdfViewer.onRendered(function(){

      Session.set("pdf", Session.get("fileUrl"));
        PDFJS.workerSrc = '/packages/pascoual_pdfjs/build/pdf.worker.js';
        // Create PDF
        PDFJS.getDocument(Session.get("pdf")).then(function getPdfHelloWorld(pdf) {
            // Fetch the first page
       Session.set("totalPages", pdf.numPages);
            pdf.getPage(1).then(function getPageHelloWorld(page) {
                var scale = 1;
                var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);

                // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions
                var canvas = document.getElementById('pdfViewer');
                var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                canvas.height = viewport.height;
                canvas.width = viewport.width;

             //Session.set("pageNumber", page.pageNumber);
                // Render PDF page into canvas context
                page.render({canvasContext: context, viewport: viewport}).promise.then(function () {

                });
            });
});
});
```

This code works fine when I pull a PDF from the public folder, but I have downloaded my PDFs to the local filesystem using [CorHTTP](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-httpd)

located at http://127.0.0.1:8080. I know the PDFs are there because when I use the PDF url from the `Session.get("pdf");` as the src for an img element, I see it.

I've heard creating an ArrayBuffer might be the fix but I have no idea how to implement that? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: if you can get a Blob, then you can use URL.createObjectURL to get a URL to feed to your lib.

Comment: Do I create a Blob and then feed it into the URL.createObjectURL method? or is URL.createObjectURL how I create the Blob?

Comment: the first case... ajax can get you a Blob, maybe your fake ajax can too.

Comment: i used this package and faced some issue. i did the same as given in package example. it gives me only the first page of the pdf as a image. No viewer is coming as given in [demo](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html)... @Optymystyc can you please tell is viewer is coming properly for you?? are you able to get all the page of pdf?? I searched a lot about this issue couldn't find any solution...

Comment: @user3135227 When I'm using a file hosted in the Public folder,  I get the first page. In order to get the second page (and subsequent pages)  I had to store the PDF url in `Session.set("pdf", url)`, the current page in `Session.set("curPage", pdf.pageNumber), and total pages in `Session.set("totalPages", pdf.numPages) then use them in a function that uses `pdf.getPage` method to change the page and rerender the PDF on the canvas.

Comment: @Optymystyc ok got your point..but you able to get this view as given in [demo](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html) of pdf.js (top tool bar and all are woking fine)???